# Nested lambdas working logic needs explanation

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I got code from here: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=25869596

```
>>> (
      lambda n: (lambda fact: fact(n, fact))(
          lambda n, inner: 1 if n == 0 else (n * inner(n - 1, inner))
      )
  )(5)
  120
```

How does this work? I particularly cannot understand how `inner` gets value.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM The question does not look *useful* beyond random trivia. Answers will be along the lines of "this values goes to that argument" with little reusability for "similar" problems, and the generic title and lack of details and keywords makes it hard to even identify "similar".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be written as

```
def func(n):

    def func1(fact):
        return fact(n, fact)

    def func2(n, inner):
        return 1 if n == 0 else (n * inner(n - 1, inner))

    return func1(func2)

func(5)
```

`inner` is `func2`, or `lambda n, inner: 1 if n == 0 else (n * inner(n - 1, inner))` in your example.

`lambda fact: fact(n, fact)` get the `lambda` as a parameter and call it recursively.